# How to compute summary statistics for age from the following data

Tags: r

I have the below-given data. Would like to convert the data from column 'year' to the age (in number of years) from present.

```
tripduration    starttime   stoptime       Year
340         1/7/2017 0:00   1/7/2017 0:05  1994
439         1/7/2017 0:02   1/7/2017 0:09  1980
186         1/7/2017 0:04   1/7/2017 0:07  1984
442         1/7/2017 0:05   1/7/2017 0:13  1969
170        1/7/2017 0:07    1/7/2017 0:10  1986
```

So, to get the solution in the first line, I tried subtracting the start time 1/7/2017 from 1994. But unable to find the difference.

Could you let me know if it is possible to find the age in number of years from the given data. What do i do to find the age in number of years from the last (year) column.

Comment: Is starttime in m/d/yyyy format or d/m/yyyy ?

Comment: I realized this doesn't matter since you are only interested in the year. I assumed d/m/yyyy as per answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You just have to convert the starttime into a year and then you can create a new column. Then you should be able to subtract the two year columns. Try this to start:

```r
df <- data.frame(starttime=c("1/7/2017 0:00"))
df
#>       starttime
#> 1 1/7/2017 0:00
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
year(strptime(df$starttime, "%d/%m/%Y"))
#> Warning in strptime(df$starttime, "%d/%m/%Y"): unknown timezone 'default/
#> America/Vancouver'
#> [1] 2017
```

And a base R solution (no need to load lubridate package):

```r
df <- data.frame(starttime=c("1/7/2017 0:00"))
df
#>       starttime
#> 1 1/7/2017 0:00
strptime(df$starttime, "%d/%m/%Y")$year + 1900
#> [1] 2017
```

Comment: thank you for providing the details. Is it possible to get the results without using the library package lubridate

Answer (score 0):

We can use the regular expression to identify the year.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "tripduration    starttime   stoptime       Year
340         '1/7/2017 0:00'   '1/7/2017 0:05'  1994
                439         '1/7/2017 0:02'   '1/7/2017 0:09'  1980
                186         '1/7/2017 0:04'   '1/7/2017 0:07'  1984
                442         '1/7/2017 0:05'   '1/7/2017 0:13'  1969
                170        '1/7/2017 0:07'    '1/7/2017 0:10'  1986",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use regular expression to get the year in starttime
dt$startYear <- as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", dt$starttime))
# Calculate the age
dt$age <- dt$startYear - dt$Year
dt
  tripduration     starttime      stoptime Year startYear age
1          340 1/7/2017 0:00 1/7/2017 0:05 1994      2017  23
2          439 1/7/2017 0:02 1/7/2017 0:09 1980      2017  37
3          186 1/7/2017 0:04 1/7/2017 0:07 1984      2017  33
4          442 1/7/2017 0:05 1/7/2017 0:13 1969      2017  48
5          170 1/7/2017 0:07 1/7/2017 0:10 1986      2017  31
```

Comment: I have a few null values as my 'Year' column. I am trying to use if (is.integer(df$Year)) { $dt$age <- dt$startyear - dt$year } However all my $age values are coming as NA

Comment: Use ifelse. Do not use if.